# PyQt runs button functions on startup

Tags: python, user-interface, button, pyqt

I created a UI using Qt Designer for a python application.

The main function of my application runs when a button is clicked, like this:

```
self.button.clicked.connect(get_data(arg1, arg2, arg3))
```

To create the UI when the program begins, here is my main method:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
```

However, the function "get_data" runs immediately upon start-up, despite the button not even rendering on my screen. 
How can I stop the function from running immediately upon start-up?

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are trying to connect the `clicked` event to the result of the function `get_data`. What you want to do is connect it to the actual function, like this:

```
self.button.clicked.connect(get_data)
```

You need to find another way to pass args into `get_data`. A `lambda` would work, but I'd use other methods (ie making a class)